# Vertically align image next to inline ul navigation bar

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Someone must have already done this but I nothing I have tried including background images and even tables works.

I have a 960 px wide wrapper, and currently the code I have displays a header on the same line as a ul navigation bar:

```
____________________________________________________________
!         h2 text          !  menu1   !  menu 2  !  menu3  ! 
____________________________________________________________
```

I want to replace the h2 text with a logo which is taller than the current text line and line everything up on the bottom like this:

```
___________________________
!                          !     
!        LOGO.jpg          !
!                          !________________________________ 
!                          !  menu1   !  menu 2  !  menu3  ! 
____________________________________________________________
```

and after trying background images, tables, and everything else I could think of, the best I can do is that the top of the logo lines up with the top of the menu bar like this.

```
____________________________________________________________
!                          !  menu1   !  menu 2  !  menu3  !   
!        LOGO.jpg          !_______________________________! 
!                          !
!                          !   
___________________________!
```

At the moment I have this code:

```
#header {
position: relative;
display: block;
background-color: #003366; 
}


#header ul {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 2px;
}

#header ul li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;
}

img.bottom 
  {
vertical-align:text-bottom;
  }
```

and

```
    <div id="header"> 
<img src="src/logo.jpg" width="414" height="140" class="bottom" />
  <div id="navbar"> 
             <ul>             
 <li><a href="menu1.htm"><span>Home</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="menu2.htm"><span>About</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="menu3.htm"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
 </div> 
    </div>
```

Is there an easy way to do move that menu down so it aligns with the bottom of the jpg?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of the header to auto and position the ul to bottom. Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YBrkB/

Comment: Thank you! That was amazingly simple and it looks like the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark the above solution as correct if it was helpful.